# How to resolve a loop in my SQL trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, insert, sql-update

I have to write a trigger which will update the message entry after its been added, to update if the message text added is 20 words or longer. I keep on getting ORA-06512 and ORA-04088 errors, which is apparently when you have an INSERT activated trigger, and your trigger is causing another INSERT, making an infinite loop.

But I have an UPDATE in my Trigger which is supposed to be triggered by an INSERT only. I can't seem to find the flaw in my logic for the code. Is there another to write this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Length
    AFTER INSERT ON Messages
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (length(new.msg_text) - length(replace(new.msg_text, ' ', '')) >= 20)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Messages
        set Messages.length = 1
        WHERE Messages.msgID = :new.msgID;
    END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this *before* the insert:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Length
    BEFORE INSERT ON Messages
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (length(:new.msg_text) - length(replace(:new.msg_text, ' ', '')) >= 20)
    BEGIN
        :new.length := 1
    END;
```

Comment: I am getting a compilation error when the trigger is created and after this when the trigger is triggered  ORA-04098: trigger 'XXXX.LENGTH' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: Yeah, there is a table of that name. Is there an alternate way to try it?

Comment: Does Messages have a column named `length`? Your question certainly suggests that it does. – Gordon Linoff

Comment: Actually, I think I had a typo when I tried your suggestion. It works now. Thank you!